# Is there a way in SQL to sum values after cross joining that account for the combination of columns?

Tags: sql

I have used SQL to generate all possible combinations of two columns, including just one column using cross joins. But while I have been able to create the combinations of columns, I am not sure how to aggregate sales accordingly per combination:

Here is what the data looked like from 'sample table':

```
Gender    Generation    Sales
Male      Baby Boomer   30
Male      Silent Gen.   40
Female    Baby Boomer   70
Female    Silent Gen.   20
```

Here is how I generated the combinations:

```
with Gendertbl AS 
(SELECT DISTINCT Gender FROM sampletable UNION select '' from sampletable),
with Generationtbl AS
(SELECT DISTINCT Generation from sampletable UNION select '' from sample table)

SELECT G1.Gender, G2.Generation
FROM sampletable G1
CROSS JOIN sampletable G2
```

This creates:

```
Gender    Generation
Male
Male      Baby Boomer
Male      Silent Gen.
Female
Female    Baby Boomer
Female    Silent Gen.
```

How would I cross-tab sales to account for just 'Male', 'Female', and 'Male-Baby Boomer'? Ideally this would create:

```
Gender    Generation    Sales
Male                    100
Male      Baby Boomer   30
Male      Silent Gen.   40
Female                  200
Female    Baby Boomer   70
Female    Silent Gen.   90
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most databases support `grouping sets`, which allow:

```
select gender, generation, sum(sales)
from sample_table
group by grouping sets ( (gender, generation), (gender) );
```

This is a simpler way to incorporate different aggregation levels in a result set.

Comment: is there another work around if that is not available? I query through Visual Studio. @GordonLinoff